# Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, sql

Trato de ejecutar la siguiente consulta en mysql que debo hacer para solucionar este error?

```
CREATE TABLE `definiciones` (
  `id_def` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `codg_def` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `categ_def` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `abrev_def` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_def` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

el error es el siguiente:

**Linea Nº 13 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'**

Comment: Después de la observación hecha espera a que otros aporten por favor, pero igual te dejo esto como referencia: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-character-set.html

Comment: Que versión de MySQL tienes?, corrí el código tal cual y no arrojo errores en mi maquina con MySQL 5.7.

Comment: la mia es version 3.5.8 ya se que debe ser 8+ pero COMO lo actualizo?

Answer (score 1):

Cambie la version de mysql y todo bien